# Xamarin Forms Timer Doesn't Show Run Code Before Timer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stopwatch

Could anyone tell me why this code does not work?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anQfj.png)

```
Random rnd = new Random();

    public PlayGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        while (true)
        {
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= rnd.Next(1000,5000))
            {
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); 
        }

        BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

What I ***expect*** to see is that the background colour is blue of the new page, and after 1-5 seconds, it should turn red.

What I ***actually*** see is that when I click the button that should lead to this new page, it doesn't show the blue background - it just pauses for 1-5 seconds and goes directly to red.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Please post the actual code not a screenshot. And read this: [Ask]

Comment: Is it better now? Anything else I can improve - I am new to the site.

Comment: You want to show your page intially blue color and after 5 seconds Red color. Is it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. After a random time between 1-5 seconds

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to change the background color from Blue to Red after 5 seconds.

```
 public partial class PlayGame : ContentPage
    {
        public PlayGame ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

                return false; 
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation as to why this works and why the original didn't?

Comment: I think it directly initializing the timer in your code.

Comment: The question was all about why the existing code didn't work. The OP did not ask for working code. Can you please explain what was wrong with the original code?

Comment: I didnt have a proper explanation for that. But I suggested an alternate solution. Thats all.